# How can I store HTML file(encrypted form) in sqlite(Cordova sqlite plugin) database in Ionic4 and angular6

Tags: sqlite, angular6, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I want to store my html file(Encrypted form) in my sqlite database.
 I am using cordova-sqlite-plugin for my ionic4 & Angular6 mobile app.
Please help me with some code or idea with this.

Comment: You should try this, then if you get stock in coding past some codes in question.

Comment: In order to match the precision (or lack thereof) of your question with an equally broad answer: You need to store either the encrypted file in total or in as small parts as you can without decrypting. I assume you cannot first decrypt. Which part of this is the problem to you? Setting up a database? Accessing a database? Reading a file? Writing a huge sequence of bytes into the database? Doing that especially with cordova? With ionic? With Angular?

Comment: Generally you can find helpful info here: [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/